# Cannot view another users' 'Drop Box' folder

Tags: macos, user-account, sharing, dropbox

I'm trying to transfer a large file between 2 different user accounts on my Mac (both are mine).

I put the file in 'Public / Drop Box' as apparently that would make it accessible to other users.

But when I log into my other user account, the Drop Box folder is empty?

Comment: What is the path of the drop box folder

Comment: `/Users/someuser/Public/Drop Box`

Comment: Whose Drop Box did you put it in? You have to put it in 'their' drop box for them to get it, after which it is 'lost' to you. You can't see into someone else's folder, as a Drop box is by definition write-only to all except its owner. I'm sure it would be simpler to just use the Shared User structure instead - which would save you having to have two copies of it on the same Mac. Or, if both are really just you, change the permissions on the user folder structure to add the other user.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, I've got it working now. I originally put it in the Drop Box of the user that I wanted to copy the file *from*... now I realise I needed to put it in the folder of the user I wanted to copy it *to*. However it won't let me put it inside the actual Drop Box folder, but I can put it in the Public folder nonetheless

Comment: I'd still be inclined to use the Shared structure - then both users can access it at any time without having to play 'pass the parcel'.